# Что означает знак "&" в этой строке?

Tags: c++

Что означает знак "&" в этой строке?

```
int a = b & 1;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Оператор **&** называется побитовым умножением или поразрядной конъюнкцией.
В Вашем примере переменной **а** присваивается значение побитового умножения **b** на **1**.
К примеру, если **b == 8**, то переведя его в двоичную систему получим **1000**. **1** в двоичной системе будет выглядеть как **0001**. Соответственно проведем побитовое умножение:

1000

0001

0000

Переведем **0000** в десятичную СС и получим число **0**, что и присвоится переменной **а**.

Answer (score 2):

"Знак `&` в этой строке" - это бинарный оператор `&`.

Что именно означает бинарный оператор `&` в данном контексте зависит от типа значения `b`. Можно лишь сказать, что это некий бинарный оператор, результат которого судя по всему неявно конвертируем к типу `int`.

Так как в вашем вопросе не содержится никакой информации о том, что такое `b`, более конкретного ответа на этот вопрос дать невозможно.

Comment: Так и вспоминаются осторожные "человек, похожий на генерального прокурора, в помещении, похожем на баню, с женщинами, похожими на проституток..." :)